# Unable to install Azure Devops agent on different domain server

Tags: azure-devops

We are not able to install Azure Devops Agent on different domain servers (client environment servers), below is the exception it is throwing when trying to install the azure devops agent on client servers. Is there any pre-requisites we need to take care so that we can install azure devops agents on different domain servers. Any client environment proxy details required or firewalls needs to be opened on client server etc... please explain in detail..

connectOptions=1&lastChangeId=-1&lastChangeId64=-1 failed (Socket Error: TimedOut). The maximum number of attempts has been reached.
[2022-08-04 11:45:08Z INFO VisualStudioServices] Finished operation Location.GetConnectionData
[2022-08-04 11:45:08Z INFO LocationServer] Unable to connect to https://dev.azure.com/AbcAzure/.
[2022-08-04 11:45:08Z ERR  LocationServer] System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.
---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (10060): A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.
at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.ConnectAsync(String host, Int32 port, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the TLS version in your server?

You could check the connection by using this script first:

(Invoke-WebRequest -Uri status.dev.azure.com).StatusDescription

It returns OK means the connection between VM and DevOps is working well.

Steps of enabling TLS 1.2:

1. Add the below DWORD value in registry editor:
   Path: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft.NETFramework\v4.0.30319
   Right-click on v4.0.30319 and add two new DWORD value named SystemDefaultTlsVersions and SchUseStrongCrypto, double-click on this value and set the value to 1 :00000001
   Same operation for the registry key like the picture below:
2. Enable below cipher suites: (Please find the cipher suites here: Deprecating weak cryptographic standards (TLS 1.0 and 1.1) in Azure DevOps Services - Azure DevOps Blog (microsoft.com) )
   Path: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Ciphers
   Right-click on Ciphers and add a new key named TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (*), right-click on this key and add a DWORD value Enabled:00000001
   It is key that on the OS one of the four TLS 1.2 cipher suites below is enabled:
   •   TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
   •   TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
   •   TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (*)
   •   TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (*)
   NOTE: (*) Cipher suites supported by Windows Server 2012 R2
3. Open Gpedit.msc (local group policy) and set the following Group policy: Computer Configuration, Administrative Templates, Network, SSL Configuration Settings > SSL Cipher Suite Order. Set the policy to enabled.
   (Please make sure the required cipher exists here, otherwise the empty cipher will overwrite the cipher in the registry key.)
4. Run GPupdate.exe /force in Admin mode.
5. Restart the virtual machine.